# Unity3D Collision combinations

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I am making a game where you form molecules with atoms (sphere GameObjects)by using the void OnMouseDrag. Just made a quick animation to show you what I really want: https://gyazo.com/334e0099af0cc2f16a14e356befe2110 . Can anyone help me with this? How could I do this? I am new to C#, but ofcourse I am here to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the order has an importance ? (I'm assuming not) I would start like that :

1)  Each atom has a unique number ID : 1, 2, 3 2)

2)  Each molecule has a unique ID, this ID is made with atoms IDs properly 
sorted (1-2-3, 6-88-55-44-66, etc...)

3)  Store combinations in a List/Dictionnary (Add())

4)  Each time the player adds an atom in the box, get all atoms in the box, sort and combine their IDs to get the combination ID.

5)  Check if your combination ID exist in your list/dictionnary (ContainsKey())

If you're new to C#, just go for it and try, this is basic. Have a look at dictionnaries.

**Edit** - For multiple combinations :
This is a bit more complex.

When dropping atom in the box =>

- If no collision, add your atom in a new molecule.
- If collision, add your atom in collided atom's molecule
- If there are  multiple collisions and your atom is now a bridge between existing molecule... You could for example find a way to convert a molecule into another. Or you can make everything explode.

Comment: This only happens when the atoms collide, not if they are just in the box. How would I be able to edit step 4) and use this with collisions? So you can actually make like 10 molecules in one box and they all get different results based on their combination ID.